# Why can't I spoof my wifi card's mac address to this address

Tags: networking, network-manager

Why can't I spoof my wifi card's mac address to `1F:2E:3D:4C:5B:6A`. Is that address invalid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first Byte `0x1F` in binary is `0001 1111`.
Since the `bit.0` in the first byte of your MAC address is set to `1`, the address corresponds to a multicast address, please see e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address#Unicast_vs._multicast).

In order to have a valid unicast address, you should always have `bit.0` set to `0`, which in your case could be achieved, e.g. by changing the MAC address to 
`1E:2E:3D:4C:5B:6A`, because `0x1E` is equal to `0001 1110`.